# How to delete all items within ListView?

Tags: java, android

I have a `ListView` display file from SD card. I want to add a button for deleting all items from `ListView` and from SD card. I tried the following, but it deletes one. And after clicking the button a second time, it deletes another one.

```
Button delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);
delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
          for (int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
              adapter.getItem(i);
              File ff = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/TestApp/" + adapter.getItem(i));
              ff.delete();
          }

          adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(i));
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just clear the data set of adapter .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the list associated with your adapter here. Then just call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter. So the sample code should look like this. Just clear the list after you have deleted all associated files in your SD card.

```
Button buy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);
buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        for (int i = 0; i < yourList.size(); i++){
            File ff = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/TestApp/" + yourList.get(i));
            ff.delete();
        }

        // Clear your list here
        yourList.clear();
        // And remove the following line
        // adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(i));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check the updated answer. Consider using the list variable that you have for populating your `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

Place following method in you adapter:

```
public void clearData(){
    list.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now Replace your code lines:

```
adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(i));
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

to This line:

```
adapter.clearData();
```